# SQL Server update where column in clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to do a Update like this

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Usuario]
SET [CAN_ID] = '1',
    [SubCanal] = 0
WHERE [Nombre] IN ('T6OU229', 'T6OU226', 'T6OU227', 'T6OU183')
```

But I got this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

It is possible to do an `UPDATE` with an `IN` clause?

Thanks

Comment: Your query has no subquery.  I can only imagine getting this error if `Usario` is a view.

Comment: Is there any trigger on the table?

Comment: I concur, the syntax is correct for an UPDATE statement, IN is absolutely supported. To confirm for yourself, try the same query to update a single value, (change `IN` to `=` - and only use a single comparison value )